# plpgsql: change order of update

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE api.capabilities (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  historycounter int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  url jsonb NOT NULL,
  checkservice bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  added timestamptz NOT NULL,
  modified timestamptz NULL,
  deleted timestamptz NULL,
  adduser varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pgsql'::character varying,
  lastuser varchar(40) NULL,
CONSTRAINT id_histcount PRIMARY KEY (id, historycounter)
);
```

With the following content:

|80af3ff3-2dc1-434b-ad3c-490d8b4a7949|1|{"host": "dev.33wessling824.net", "protocol": "http"}|false|2022-07-12 18:35:17.465 +0200|||pgsql||

|80af3ff3-2dc1-434b-ad3c-490d8b4a7949|0|{"host": "dev.33wessling824.net", "protocol": "http"}|true|2022-07-12 18:35:17.465 +0200|2022-07-14 11:46:50.073 +0200||pgsql||

I'd like to run this update statement:

```
Update api.capabilities set historycounter = historycounter + 1 where id = '80af3ff3-2dc1-434b-ad3c-490d8b4a7949';
```

Trying this results in an error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "id_histcount"`

Because first the dataset with `historycounter = 0` is updated, I do get this error. How to change my code to first update the dataset with the biggest historycounter?

Thanks in advance! Achim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are totally sure that your data will not violate primary key after your transaction. First, alter table constraint. This is safe:

```
ALTER TABLE api.capabilities
ALTER CONSTRAINT id_histcount DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

Then in your transaction:

```
begin transaction;

set constraints all deferred;
Update api.capabilities set historycounter = historycounter + 1 where id = '80af3ff3-2dc1-434b-ad3c-490d8b4a7949';
--your other operations

commit transaction;
```

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html

Comment: Not necessary, If OP was sure that the update would *not violate primary key after the transaction* and was correct then the error would not occur in the first place.